# Meeting link using google calendar API

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to generate meeting link using google calender api in node.js and that meeting is only accessable to attendees mention in the code directly, so how can i do that.

here is code for generating meeting but it is restricted to attendees.

```
const event = {
    summary: 'Meeting event',
    location: 'India',
    description: 'Meeting with Doctor',
    start: {
      dateTime: eventStartTime.toISOString(),
      timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: eventEndTime.toISOString(),
      timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
    },
    visibility: 'public',
    guestsCanModify: true,
    conferenceData: {
      createRequest: {
        requestId: 'create-meeting',
        conferenceSolutionKey: {
          type: 'hangoutsMeet'
        }
      }
    },
    attendees: [
           { email: 'attendee1@example.com' },
           { email: 'attendee2@example.com' }
          ],
    
    colorId: 3,
  };
  
  calendar.events.insert({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    conferenceDataVersion: 1,
    resource: event,
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error creating event:', err);
      return;
    }
  
    const eventId = res.data.id;
    console.log('Event created:', res);
  });
```

how to make these attendiees to access this meeting directly